# Library to embed a form on a website site to automatically post on Stack Exchange

Tags: library, web-development, stack-exchange

I would like to embed a form on my website to automatically create questions on Stack Exchange (with a specific tag). I am looking for a library to wrap posting questions on Stack Exchange, so that the asker doesn't have to go to Stack Exchange to post the question.

Comment: Wouldn't the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) be sufficient for that?